# tesseract-php wrapper having a path error while running on localhost

Tags: php, path, xampp, ocr, tesseract

So I am using the tesseract-php wrapper given here https://github.com/thiagoalessio/tesseract-ocr-for-php.
Here's what my php code looks like:

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";
use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;
echo (new TesseractOCR('image1.jpeg'))->run();
?>
```

On running via cmd, it works just fine. However, while trying to run on xampp server, I'm getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractNotFoundException: 
Error! The command "tesseract" was not found. Make sure you have Tesseract 
OCR installed on your system: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract The 
current $PATH is C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files 
(x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program 
Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_151\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\
in C:\xampp\htdocs\tesseract_project\vendor\thiagoalessio\tesseract_ocr\src\FriendlyErrors.php on line 42
```

I read a few answers here, and turns out adding this would help

```
$path = getenv('PATH');
putenv("PATH=$path:C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR");
```

However, there's no change, and I'm still getting the same error. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

INSTALL TESSERACT IN YOUR SYSTEM THEN Define a custom location of the tesseract executable, if by any reason it is not present in the $PATH.

```
->executable('/path/to/tesseract')
->run();
```

Comment: not work ->executable('/path/to/tesseract')
->run();

Answer (score 0):

After make sure the path is done. The next you can try is change the code to this for windows 11 enviroment.

```
 (new TesseractOCR('download.png'))
                ->executable('C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe')
                ->run();
```